# Why isn't <IfModule mod_version.c> working in Apache?

Tags: debian, apache-2.4

Bugzilla upstream ships a `.htaccess` file that contains, among other things, this snippet of Apache configuration:

```
# Don't allow people to retrieve non-cgi executable files or our private data
<FilesMatch (\.pm|\.pl|\.tmpl|localconfig.*)$>
  <IfModule mod_version.c>
    <IfVersion < 2.4>
      Deny from all
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion >= 2.4>
      Require all denied
    </IfVersion>
  </IfModule>
  <IfModule !mod_version.c>
    Deny from all
  </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I'm running Apache 2.4; however I get 500 errors about `Deny` whenever I visit the Bugzilla homepage. Turns out that Apache is getting `Deny from all` from inside the `<IfModule !mod_version.c>` block, and changing this to `Require all denied` fixes the errors. Other `<IfModule>` blocks for e.g. mod_rewrite work OK.

Why is Apache behaving this way? I've searched the web pretty extensively with no luck.

Here's some more info about my system:

```
% sudo apachectl -M | grep version
 version_module (static)

% uname -a # Debian 8
Linux steevie 4.9.0-0.bpo.3-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2~bpo8+1 (2017-06-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux

% apachectl -v 
Server version: Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)
Server built:   Jul 18 2017 18:32:16
```

Comment: It's not a module, it's compiled statitically, perhaps just that, remove the IfModule directive and try again, it makes no sense to use IfModule if it has been statically added to the httpd binary.

Comment: @ezra-s yeah I had that thought too - of course I could just fix this myself but I wanted to send a patch to upstream too